# Configuring hyperlink navigation from entity to entity with Spring Roo and Spring MVC

Tags: jpa, spring-mvc, spring-roo, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I use Spring Roo + Jpa + Spring MVC. I have several @ManyToOne and @OneToMany relationships in my domain. Furthermore, I have generated web scaffolds for my entities.

So say I have a

> client---order

relationship (one client having several orders). As of now, the scaffolds I have generated allow me to see for a given order what is the client for that order.

However, the client is shown as **plain text**. What I need is **a link to navigate to the client from a given order**.

Is that possible to achieve with the Spring Roo shell for all @ManyToOne relationships or do I have to edit the JSPs manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit roo-generated JSP pages manually to add hyperlink behavior.